# Phusion Passenger + Apache + Node.js app runs on http but not https. 404 Error

Tags: node.js, cpanel, passenger

I have a Phusion Passenger Node.js application configured with cPanel that ran perfectly on my primary domain. I created a new application that uses the same path but switched the domain to another domain on my account. On the old domain: ghv.xie.mybluehost.me, the application worked on both http and https.

[http://ghv.xie.mybluehost.me/portal](https://ghv.xie.mybluehost.me/portal)
[https://ghv.xie.mybluehost.me/portal](http://ghv.xie.mybluehost.me/portal)

On the new domain: csmithcpa.com, the app only works on http. https returns a 404 error.

http://csmithcpa.com/portal
https://csmithcpa.com/portal

I am not sure how to debug this or why it would return a 404 at all on https but completely work on http. Any help would be fantastic.

EDIT: I will keep adding useful information for debugging as more people ask questions about it.

cPanel/WHM access
Apache server
Phusion Passenger application manager
Node.js web application

-portal
--app.js
--node_modules
-public_html
--ghv.xie.mybluehost.me site files
--csmithcpa
---csmithcpa.com site files